# This file server type is not recognized

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to access Windows share in Ubuntu 16.04 using GUI.

It is giving error like this
[image]

I am able to access same share in ubuntu 14.04. 
In Ubuntu 16 whenever i type smb:// it will generate error saying "This file server type is not recognized" What is the issue?

Comment: Try to access server by IP address `smb://ip.ip.ip.ip/ShareName`

Comment: I tried already. It is not working.  When I type "smb:" it will show error message "This file server type is not recognized" . You can check the snapshot. I didn't type IP address there.

Comment: try this `sudo printf "\n%s\n" "client use spnego = no" >>/etc/samba/smb.conf`

Comment: Just now I checked, It is not only for smb, for ssh,sftp for everything it is showing same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Happened to me and found this solution here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1617107

TL;DR:

you need the gvfs packages listed there.

For me, the gvfs-backends was missing so do: 
`sudo apt install gvfs-backends`

logged out, logged in, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with GVFS.

First,install samba: `sudo apt install samba`

The second,install the gvfs-backends: `sudo apt install gvfs-backends`

logged out and logged in.

Open nautilus,the file manager, and press ctrl+L. This will give you a text field where you can type.
`smb://ip.ip.ip.ip/ShareName`

you can also select "connect to server", and type `smb://ip.ip.ip.ip/ShareName`.